# toyota Hilux 2008 trayback model brake problem

Tags: toyota, hilux

Problem with brakes going flat to floor-
have bled and just replaced  my drum brakes, other brakes done also but brake pedal still goes flat to floor????

please could you give me some advice as to what I should do from here????
thank you in advance

Comment: Either it wasn't a proper bleed, or you have a master cylinder problem.  Sometimes bleeds are finicky.  In the end there's no magic.  Pressure bleed if you have the eqiupment, or drip bleed if you don't.  Watch the reservoir for bubbles.  Drums are more effort than cylinders.

Comment: Could you explain the order of events?  Did you replace parts because of the pedal going to the floor, or did the problem start after some maintenance?

Comment: Hello, I would just like to update on the recent post requesting help for brake problem; it would appear it as just air in the line which caused this short-term problem; it has now resolved. I would like to thank the people that offered their assistance to me, very helpful and kind.